# Reselecting Selected Item on DropDownListFor with serverside failed validation with MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Create page that have a Dropdownlist with Players

This I populate in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new CreateMatchViewModel
                    {
                        Winner =
                            CreateWinnerList(),
                        PlayerList = CreatePlayerList()
                    }
        ;

    return View(vm);
}

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreatePlayerList()
{
    List<Player> playerList = _playerManagementRepository.GetAllPlayers();
    return playerList.Select(p => new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                            Text = p.Username,
                                            Value = p.Id.ToString()
                                        });
}

private SelectListItem[] CreateWinnerList()
{
    return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Player 1", Value = 1.ToString(), Selected = true}
                    , new SelectListItem {Text = "Player 2", Value = 2.ToString(), Selected = false}
                };
}
```

This populates my view fine

```
@model TableTennis.ViewModels.CreateMatchViewModel

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Enter Match Result";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Match", FormMethod.Post))
{
<h4>Player 1</h4>
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.Player1ID, Model.PlayerList)   

<h4>Player 2</h4>
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.Player2ID, Model.PlayerList)

<h4>Winner</h4>
@Html.DropDownListFor(w => w.WinnerID, Model.Winner)

<h5>Set 1</h5>
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.Score1Set1)
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.Score2Set1)
<h5>Set 2</h5>
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.Score1Set2)
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.Score2Set2)

<h5>Set 3</h5>
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.Score1Set3)
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.Score2Set3)

<input type="submit" value="Add result" />    
}
```

Then on Post I do some validation where ModelState is not valid, so the following is run

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateMatchViewModel vm)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            vm.PlayerList = CreatePlayerList();
            vm.Winner = CreateWinnerList();
            return View(vm);
        }
```

But this fails follwing error, but I am not sure how to cast the Guid to a SelectedListItem so that the same item in the list is selected again on the new Get request

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Player1ID' is of type 'System.Guid' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

ViewModel

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TableTennis.ViewModels
{
    public class CreateMatchViewModel
    {
        public CreateMatchViewModel()
        {
            Score1Set1 = 0;
            Score1Set2 = 0;
            Score1Set3 = 0;
            Score2Set1 = 0;
            Score2Set2 = 0;
            Score2Set3 = 0;
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PlayerList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Winner { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid Player1ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid Player2ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int WinnerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("[0-9][0-9]?")]
        public int Score1Set1 { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("[0-9][0-9]?")]
        [Required]
        public int Score1Set2 { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("[0-9][0-9]?")]
        [Required]
        public int Score1Set3 { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("[0-9][0-9]?")]
        [Required]
        public int Score2Set1 { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("[0-9][0-9]?")]
        [Required]
        public int Score2Set2 { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("[0-9][0-9]?")]
        [Required]
        public int Score2Set3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This made it work

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    vm.PlayerList = CreatePlayerList();
    vm.Winner = CreateWinnerList();
    return View(vm);
}
if (vm.Player1ID == vm.Player2ID)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    vm.PlayerList = CreatePlayerList();
    vm.Winner = CreateWinnerList();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer:
Problem is that in your CreatePlayerList() method you are casting the id to a string so MVC is unable to get the selected item based on the id in your model, which is a guid.  Player1ID and Player2ID need to be strings in your ViewModel, no matter what you do with them in your database.

Actual answer, fished out of the comments:
The problem, despite the text of the error message is NOT that Player1ID needs to be IEnumerable or IEnumerable but that the list is gone from the model, or the list does not contain the ID. You (may) need to examine the ViewModel when ModelState is not valid and determine what is not valid and why. You may have to use ModelState.Remove() along with reconstructing what is faulty in your Model.

Comment: Making them Strings just got me The ViewData item that has the key 'Player1ID' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure.  I do this all the time, and the only thing I do different is that I create the model from scratch rather than just re-populating the lists as you are.  It would possibly help to know what is not valid in your ModelState.

Comment: But how do you select the SelectedIndex on recreate then?

Comment: Hmm...pick it off and put it back after recreating the model.

Comment: Another suggestion I've seen is to add the lists into ViewData rather than into your model....

Comment: But I cant set the Player1ID even if I pick the value from the ViewModel I get back as its still a Guid, how is it you would set it with ViewData that would be different from what I am doing?

Comment: I'm running out of gas on this one, but here goes.  Everything I have seen indicates that this error message is confusing.  The problem, despite the text of the error message is NOT that Player1ID needs to be IEnumerable or IEnumerable<SelectListItem> but that the list is gone from the model, or the list does not contain the ID.  You need to examine the ViewModel when ModelState is not valid and determine what is not valid and why.  You may have to use ModelState.Remove() along with reconstructing what is faulty in your Model.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I was just looking through a project of ours...since we are both stumped here, try putting "ModelState.Clear();" in your !ModelState.IsValid block.

Comment: Yes that is confusing, but Modelstate.Clear seems to work thanks!